# Align pseudo selector image correctly

Tags: css, pseudo-element

How do I use margin or padding for pseudo element `:before` to give enough space between image and number

[Look here in this link for screenshot](https://prnt.sc/mwjj5q)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>city</li>
            <li>email</li>
            <li>adress</li>
            <li>0202020202</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[the code is here](https://codepen.io/youssefkhoukhou/pen/rRGjJW)

Thanks a lot  in advance for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you share the source of the `phone-pic.png`, I could give you a more accurate answer to this problem.

Comment: here you are @Demian https://prnt.sc/mwjs4r

Comment: I think you will be better of using font-awesome for the icon. and once you try and post your code we can help you.  try `pos:a`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired [prnscrn](https://prnt.sc/mwk5aa)

You need to play around with the `margin-left` of the `:before` pseudo selector and put `bottom` on `0`. With the below `CSS` it should result correctly:

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c9qsj7fb/).

**CSS**

```
li:nth-child(4)::before {
    content: url('https://image.prntscr.com/image/RsidxDk_QzytthM_zz4H8Q.png');
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -2.7em;
    bottom: 0;
    zoom: 0.8;
}
```

Use `zoom` in this instance to reduce the size and use for `margin-left` the unit `em` so it will take the font-size of the element. (Be also aware that there are a lot of errors in your provided CSS).

Comment: @youssefkhoukhou I have updated the fiddle and answer. You can change the `zoom` and `margin-left` yourself to position it correctly. Be aware that `li:nth-child(4)` itself doesn't need anything. Als het antwoord in orde is, upvote het voor me :)

Comment: NO WAY ben jij nederlander mmmmm Lol

Comment: @youssefkhoukhou What do you mean by Menner?

Comment: @Demain i mean Meneer haha , Sir.

Comment: Ah! Maar je moet ff een keus maken welk antwoord je vraag beantwoord. Anders blijven vragen onbeantwoord. Zo werkt StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to show the pic as a background. Then you can positioning easily your icon.

```
ul li:nth-child(4)::before {
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(image.png) no-repeat right top;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    left: -30px;
    top: 0;
}
```

[Here in your code](https://codepen.io/susanasanz9/pen/rRGjgw?editors=1100)

Comment: The only problem to your answer is the size measured in `px`, this won't work for different screen sizes. I would use unit `%` or `rem`. Be aware he asked specifically for a margin solution, for this instance there are a dozen of different solutions - approaches.